# Get groups which does not match the specified pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on C# to retrieve sub strings from a specified string.

Ex: I have a string like that:

> \a{Doc Title}\aDoc ID\rDoc Date\rDoc Version\rDoc Status\a:\r:\r:\r:\a{DocID}\r{DocDate}\r{DocVersion}\r{DocStatus}\a\a\r

Then I want to get all sub strings between "\a""\r","\a:\r:\r:\r:\a"...
I already created a pattern to match with all "\a","\r",... as bellow:

```
((\\a[:]{0,1})+|(\\r[:]{0,1})+)+
```

The problem is: how can I get all sub string that does not match the above patterns?

Expected result is: "{Doc Title}", "Doc ID", "Doc Date",...

Comment: why can't you use a negation in regular expression ?

Comment: First of all, please shorten your regex. `{0,1}` is `?`. `[:]` is simply `:`. Shortend version of your regex is `(\\[ar]:?)+`. This regex allowes backtracking what makes it harder to use in a split operation. Avoid it by using an atomic group: `(?>\\[ar]:?)+` And now you can split your string to get all the other strings and filter empty strings: [DEMO](https://ideone.com/gGh8SM) Does this help?

Comment: @Arunprasanth K V : Because I don't know how to use it correctly. Anyway, I got my answer from  Vera rind .

Comment: @Vera rind: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please shorten your regex.

- `{0,1}` is `?`
- `[:]` is simply `:`

Shortend version of your regex is `(\\[ar]:?)+`. This regex allowes backtracking what makes it harder to use in a split operation. Avoid it by using an atomic group: `(?>\\[ar]:?)+` And now you can split your string to get all the other strings and filter empty strings:

```
var input = @"\a{Doc Title}\aDoc ID\rDoc Date\rDoc Version\rDoc Status\a:\r:\r:\r:\a{DocID}\r{DocDate}\r{DocVersion}\r{DocStatus}\a\a\r";
var pattern = @"(?>\\[ar]:?)+";
var items = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (var item in items)
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/gGh8SM)